# ConcurrentDictionary - Converting addValueFactory (Func<string, T, T> ) into an updateValueFactory (Func<string, T, T>)?

Tags: c#, delegates, concurrentdictionary

I am working with a method that, internally, calls [`ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378676%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I would like to add a call to [`ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378675%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) insde the same method.

However the containing method only receives an `addValueFactory` parameter (`Func<string, T>`).

To call the `AddOrUpdate()` method, I also need an `updateValueFactory` (`Func<string, T, T>`).  But I don't want to change the method signature.

Ideally, I'd like to use the existing  `addValueFactory` function to create an `updateValueFactory` function that will produce the same `T` result.

*Is there any way I can convert the addValueFactory (`Func<string, T>`)  into an udpateValueFactory (`Func<string, T, T>`)?*

---

```
public SomeMethod(string key, Func<string, T> addValueFactory)
{
    // existing code
    concurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd(key, addValueFactory)

    // code to add
    // but how to transform (Func<string, T>) into Func<string, T, T>?

    var updateValueFactory = ? 
    concurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate(key, addValueFactory, updateValueFactory)
}
```

I wasn't 100% sure what tags to use for this. Please update them if you think they could be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it a lambda with unused parameter:

```
var updateValueFactory = (Func<String, T, T>)((str, old) => addValueFactory(str));
```